# React Native Share file or link

Tags: android, react-native, expo

[image]

Not sure what this is called, but on Android an app is able to bring up this window, and if I select, say Gmail, it will automatically create a file attachment in Gmail.

How can I achieve this in React Native with Expo (without detaching)?

Comment: You can use React Native Share.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47078347

Comment: @heltdev I'm using Expo and want to avoid detaching if possible.

Comment: single or multiple images sharing using react-native-share, answer by me with more detailed info here, checkout  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for something like [react-native-share](https://github.com/EstebanFuentealba/react-native-share).

Since you're using Expo, you'll probably want to use [Linking (Opening links to other apps)](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking#opening-links-to-other-apps) which points you to using [react-native-app-link](https://github.com/fiber-god/react-native-app-link). Or for something more complicated on the Android side, the [IntentLauncherAndroid](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v26.0.0/sdk/intent-launcher) with some custom code could work as well.

Keywords to help you look for more information are *sharing*, *linking*, *deep linking*, and if you know Android development, *Intents*.

Comment: I want to share a file. RN's `Share` does exactly what I want on iOS but does not support file url for Android, and `react-native-share` will require detaching from `Expo`. How do I use `IntentLauncherAndroid` to share a file?

Answer (score 0):

Without ejecting the IntentLauncherAndroid is the way to go, since you can emit intents for anything listed at the [Android Dev Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_SEND)

For an intend to share a file based on an URI you can do: 
`IntentLauncherAndroid.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.SEND", { URI: uri });`

This also works to open a file with the default app on a device:

`IntentLauncherAndroid.startActivityAsync("android.intent.action.VIEW", { URI: uri });`

Answer (score 0):

Try these package, it can support all file format 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-share-for-android