# How to create a file extension using react-native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, expo

im building a notebloc with react-native, now im implementing the share section, the problem is that when I select the app that I want share with, I want to share the note with an extension, and not only text, for example like in java when someone saves the data in a .txt, well, thats what Im trying to do in react-native, get the data, save it in a .html document and send it, for now im just using the default example of react:

```
share = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await Share.share({
          message: 'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React',
        });
        
        if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
            
            console.log(JSON.parse(result.activityType));
        }
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }
}
```

so when I select the app that I want to share with it will send `'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React'`, but I want to send `Note.html`, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as an "extension" here because you are not saving a file. According to [the documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share#share):

> Open a dialog to share text content.

So you can only share plain text with `Share.share()`.

Comment: but I cant create the file then send it? thats what im asking, create the file then send it

Comment: @plus I'm sure there is a way. You just can't do it with `Share.share()`. I googled "react native share file" and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819168/react-native-share-file-or-link). Hopefully it will help get you headed in the right direction.